# Type T = Type.GetType(TypeName); T is returning Null

Tags: c#

Its a simple program where I am passing System.Console and it will return me the Methods it has by using Reflection ... Here Type object T is taking Null even after I am passing System.Console in txtTypeName.Text

My Code :

```
    string TypeName = txtTypeName.Text;
    Type T  = Type.GetType(TypeName,true);

    MethodInfo[] methods = T.GetMethods();
    foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
    {
        lstMethod.Items.Add(method.Name);
    }
```

`Type T = Type.GetType(TypeName);` `T` is returning Null

Comment: Please add the error/exception to your question as text, not an image.  What is the value of `txtTypeName.Text`?  Does the type exist?

Comment: What are you passing as input  ?

Comment: You say "it returns null" but the image shows or throws an exception. That's not the same. What are you trying to do?

Comment: System.Console is passed as input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `Type.GetType()` has changed for .net Core and later*.

This code works with .net 4.8:

```
Type? t = Type.GetType("System.Console", true);
Console.WriteLine(t!.FullName);
```

But it fails in .net Core and later!

Repro showing it not working in .net 6.0: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JlAhqn

Repro showing it working in .net 4.7.2: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahV7fC

To make this work in .net Core or later you need to specify the assembly-qualified name of the type, which includes the name of the assembly from which this Type object was loaded.

For the type `System.Console` the assembly name is also "System.Console" so the following works in .net Core *and* .net Framework:

```
Type? t = Type.GetType("System.Console, System.Console", true);
Console.WriteLine(t!.FullName);
```

Repro showing it working in .net 6.0: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dA1ulx

---

*As noted by the other answer, the behaviour has changed for "System.Console" because it was moved to another assembly.

There have been some other changes in the area that can affect `Type.GetType()`, specifically because of changes to `Assembly.LoadFrom()` but those changes aren't causing this effect.

See here for details: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12376

Comment: Careful.  That "System.Console, System.Console" works is a bit of an accident and only possible because 4.7.2+ supports .NETStandard assemblies.  System.Console.dll doesn't contain any code and doesn't get referenced in a .NETFramework project, it merely forwards types to mscorlib.

Comment: Type? t = Type.GetType("System.Console, System.Console", true);
Console.WriteLine(t!.FullName);

It worked .. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe the behaviour changed. It's because the type moved to a different assembly, but in older frameworks it's in the BCL which doesn't need a fully-qualified name

Answer (score 5):

**The accepted answer is not quite correct.**

The behaviour of `Type.GetType` did *not* change between framework versions. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#system-type-gettype(system-string)) in both of them states *(my bold)*:

> **Parameters**
>
> `typeName` `String`
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.8#system-type-assemblyqualifiedname). If the type is in the currently executing assembly **or in mscorlib.dll/System.Private.CoreLib.dll**, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Only types that are in the calling assembly or in the BCL assembly do not need qualification. The difference between the two version of the framework is simply that `System.Console` got moved to a different assembly, so that is why it is failing. The docs for [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0) shows `System.Console.dll`, while [NET 4.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.7.2) shows `mscorlib.dll`

You can, for example, see in these two fiddles what happens if you try `System.DateTime` without qualification: it works in both cases.
[.NET 4.7](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vy7tLf)
[.NET 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpMHB6)